# The coefficient of one variable in Cox regression becames negative when doing multiple variable regression

Tags: r, survival

I am doing Cox proportional regression. I first did Cox regression with only one variable `var`; its coefficient 0.8752721 was about what I expected and is easy to interpret in my situation. But when I added some other variables, the coefficient of `var` in the model became negative (-0.894304). I have performed the stepwise process. The negative coefficient seems wrong and is hard to interpret in my problem.

Where am I wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Note to others: I was going to mark this as a duplicate, but it seems to me to ask more than one question, each of which is duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

First, you shouldn't use stepwise; you can search on the term, it's been discussed a lot here.

Second, when you add another variable you ask a different question, so you get a different answer. Specially, you ask about the effect of the variables while controlling for (holding constant) other variables.

Third, unless you show your code, we can't tell if you made an error there, but, assuming you did not, then the new model isn't wrong and it does explain your data. But there could be some complications. One thing, the variables could be collinear (search on that term too, and on multicollinearity, both have been discussed a lot).

Fourth, if you haven't made any errors and there are no other data problems, then you have a surprising result. My favorite professor in grad school used to say "If you're not surprised, you haven't learned anything".

Finally, if you tell us what these variables are, we might be able to tell what is going on. You may find [this post](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) from my blog useful.

Comment: thanks for you reply. I have 55 variables in my data set (60x55), including both categorical and quantitative variables. First, I made univariate regression on each varible, and then select variables whose p-values are significant, denoted by V_1. Second, with the variables in V_1, I made  a cox regression on these variables, and then used stepwise method to select the final variables. I know stepwise is a way to select variables. Maybe should I select variables manually? Alternatively, I used penalized cox model to select variables automaticly, which gave a more interpretive model.

Comment: Penalized Cox looks better than bivariate screening and stepwise. The latter are not recommended.

Comment: "The latter", did you mean selecting variables manually is not recommended? Thanks.

Comment: No, I meant doing bivariate screening is not recommended, nor is stepwise.